# Fortran nested WHERE statement

Tags: nested, fortran, where-clause, fortran90

I have a Fortran 90 source code with a nested WHERE statement. There is a problem but it seems difficult to understand what exactly happens. I would like to transform it into DO-IF structure in order to debug. What it is not clear to me is how to translate the nested WHERE.

All the arrays have the same size.

```
WHERE (arrayA(:) > 0)
    diff_frac(:) = 1.5 * arrayA(:)
    WHERE (diff_frac(:) > 2)
        arrayC(:) = arrayC(:) + diff_frac(:)
    ENDWHERE
ENDWHERE
```

My option A:

```
DO i=1, SIZE(arrayA)
  IF (arrayA(i) > 0) THEN
    diff_frac(i) = 1.5 * arrayA(i)
    DO j=1, SIZE(diff_frac)
      IF (diff_frac(j) > 2) THEN
          arrayC(j) = arrayC(j) + diff_frac(j)
      ENDIF
    ENDDO
  ENDIF
ENDDO
```

My option B:

```
DO i=1, SIZE(arrayA)
  IF (arrayA(i) > 0) THEN
    diff_frac(i) = 1.5 * arrayA(i)        
    IF (diff_frac(i) > 2) THEN
        arrayC(i) = arrayC(i) + diff_frac(i)
    ENDIF        
  ENDIF
ENDDO
```

Thank you

Comment: It seems, (inferred by testing)  The inner `where` is effectively an `if` block operating on the single element identified by the outer `where` mask.  That should make conversion to `do` easy, and it seems your "option B" is correct.  Why (if) the standards allow this ambiguous construct instead of just using `if` is a good question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the thread ["Nested WHERE constructs](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.fortran/EG2k49ujggA)" in comp.lang.fortran (particularly Ian's reply), it seems that the first code in the Question translates to the following:

```
do i = 1, size( arrayA )
    if ( arrayA( i ) > 0 ) then
        diff_frac( i ) = 1.5 * arrayA( i )
    endif
enddo

do i = 1, size( arrayA )
    if ( arrayA( i ) > 0 ) then
        if ( diff_frac( i ) > 2 ) then
            arrayC( i ) = arrayC( i ) + diff_frac( i )
        endif
    endif
enddo
```

This is almost the same as that in Mark's answer except for the second mask part (see below). Key excerpts from the [F2008](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/fortran/info) documents are something like this:

> 7.2.3 Masked array assignment – WHERE   (page 161)
>
> 7.2.3.2 Interpretation of masked array assignments   (page 162)
>
> ... 2. Each statement in a WHERE construct is executed in sequence.
>
> ... 4. The *mask-expr* is evaluated at most once.
>
> ... 8. Upon execution of a WHERE statement that is part of a *where-body-construct*, the control mask is established to have the value m_c .AND. *mask-expr*.
>
> ... 10. If an elemental operation or function reference occurs in the *expr* or *variable* of a *where-assignment-stmt* or in a *mask-expr*, and is not within the argument list of a nonelemental function reference, the operation is performed or the function is evaluated only for the elements corresponding to true values of the control mask.

If I understand the above thread/documents correctly, the conditional `diff_frac( i ) > 2` is evaluated after `arrayA( i ) > 0`, so corresponding to double IF blocks (if I assume that `A .and. B` in Fortran does not specify the order of evaluation).

---

However, as noted in the above thread, the actual behavior may depend on compilers... For example, if we compile the following code with gfortran5.2, ifort14.0, or Oracle fortran 12.4 (with no options)

```
integer, dimension(4) :: x, y, z
integer :: i

x = [1,2,3,4]
y = 0 ; z = 0

where ( 2 <= x )
   y = x
   where ( 3.0 / y < 1.001 )  !! possible division by zero
      z = -10
   end where
end where

print *, "x = ", x
print *, "y = ", y
print *, "z = ", z
```

they all give the expected result:

```
x =            1           2           3           4
y =            0           2           3           4
z =            0           0         -10         -10
```

But if we compile with debugging options

```
gfortran -ffpe-trap=zero
ifort -fpe0
f95 -ftrap=division  (or with -fnonstd)
```

gfortran and ifort abort with floating-point exception by evaluating `y(i) = 0` in the mask expression, while f95 runs with no complaints. (According to the linked thread, Cray behaves similarly to gfortran/ifort, while NAG/PGI/XLF are similar to f95.)

---

As a side note, when we use "nonelemental" functions in WHERE constructs, the control mask does not apply and all the elements are used in the function evaluation (according to Sec. 7.2.3.2, sentence 9 of the draft above). For example, the following code

```
integer, dimension(4) :: a, b, c

a = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
b = -1 ; c = -1

where ( 3 <= a )
    b = a * 100
    c = sum( b )
endwhere
```

gives

```
a =  1 2 3 4
b =  -1 -1 300 400
c =  -1 -1 698 698
```

which means that sum( b ) = 698 is obtained from all the elements of b, with the two statements evaluated in sequence.

Comment: I gathered info from the net (sorry for a long post!) and if the explanation is wrong please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Why not

```
WHERE (arrayA(:) > 0)
    diff_frac(:) = 1.5 * arrayA(:)
ENDWHERE

WHERE (diff_frac(:) > 2 .and. arrayA(:) > 0)
    arrayC(:) = arrayC(:) + diff_frac(:)
ENDWHERE
```

?

I won't say it can't be done with nested `where`s, but I don't see why it has to be.  Then, if you must translate to `do` loops, the translation is very straightforward.

Your own attempts suggest you think of `where` as a kind of looping construct, I think it's better to think of it as a masked assignment (which is how it's explained in the language standard) in which each individual assignment happens at the same time.  These days you might consider translating into `do concurrent` constructs.

Comment: I definitely like your approach. Are them exactly the same compared to the one I posted? My point on this is if the nested WHERE is also evaluated.

Comment: I also think it does the same. With the last sentence I meant that diff_frac will also be checked (> 2) even if arrayA is negative. That is my question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about deflecting the question a bit, but this is interesting. I am not sure that I can tell how the nested `where` is going to be compiled. It may even be one of those cases that push the envelope.

I agree with [High Performance Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44309/high-performance-mark) that `where` is best thought of as a masking operation and then it is unclear (to me) whether your "*A*" or "*B*" will result.
I do think that his solution should be the same as your nested `where`.

My point: Since this is tricky to even discern, can you write new code instead of this, from scratch?  Not to translate it, but delete it, forget about it, and write code to do the job.

If you know exactly what this piece of code needs to do, its pre- and post- conditions, then it shouldn't be difficult. If you don't know that then the algorithm may be too entangled in which case this should be rewritten anyway. There may be subtleties involved between what this was intended to do and what it does. You say you *are* debugging this code already.

Again, sorry to switch context but I think that there is a possibility that this is one of those situations where code is best served by a complete rewrite.

---

If you want to keep it and only write loops for debugging: Why not write them and compare output? 

Run it with `where` as it is, then run it with "*A*" instead, then with "*B*".  Print values.